# Why Electrostatic field has a continuous curve?

Tags: electrostatics

An electrostatic field line is a continuous curve. That is, a field line cannot have sudden breaks. Why not ?

Comment: There is nothing very meaningful here. A field line is a curve $\vec{x}(t)$ for which $\vec{x}'(t)=\vec{E}(\vec{x}(t))$ for some vector field $\vec{E}$. In order to satisfy this equation, $\vec{x}'(t)$ must exist, so it can't have any breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maxwell's equation: $$\nabla \cdot   E=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$$

If this has to hold true $E$ must be differentiable at all points, so it has to be continuous (except at boundaries of surface charge)

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with some logic.The field lines are made by joining the forces, which is in the direction of the field line.These forces are actually produced by waves generated from the source charge in test charge and you know that these waves are generated continuously so we do not find breaks.
If certainly it were discontinuous then something might be opposing the force in the break which must be equal and opposite.This could be done by the same type of charge as like charges repel each other and if the charge is there it would bend the field lines making it continuous not break it applying superposition principle.